# Procmon "Load Image" and Hello World

Tags: windows-10, procmon

I wrote a 32 bits C++ Hello World program. Then I watched it execution through SysInternal's Procmon. To my surprise I have 5 events of type "Load Image". The following were loaded:

- ntdll.dll
- kernel32.dll
- KernelBase.dll
- apphelp.dll
- msvcrt.dll

msvcrt.dll and kernel32.dll are DLL imported by my Hello World program. So it is expected to load.

According with my research Windows loads apphelp.dll into my process as part of Application Compatibility.

I would like to know:

1. Why does Windows also loads ntdll.dll?
2. Why does Windows also loads KernelBase.dll?
3. Is the process of loading unsolicited DLLs into process called DLL Hooking?

PS: I'm using the latest Windows 10 release.

Comment: Look inside the DLL files.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050615/how-to-open-dll-files-to-see-what-is-written-inside

Comment: @Gantendo The linked question is about Dot.Net DLL files, those tools don't work for common 32/64 bit DLL files compiled from C/C++ to x86/x86_64 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what functions you are importing from the other libraries they may in turn import other libraries.

For example [many functions in `Kernel32` actually import `KernelBase`](https://github.com/kkent030315/kernel32-imports) and there is nothing stopping `KernelBase` from then importing functions from `ntdll` to perform basic tasks your program needs.

Comment: Mokubai, thank you for your information. 

According with the provided link kernel32.dll also imports *api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-2* and a bunch more dlls. 

Shouldn't I see these on procmon? Or Windows is smart enough to know that my application would only use a subset of kernel32.dll? 

If that's the case could you please point me some references?